# Do I need Windows CALs for a dedicated SQL Server database server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

This would seem an easy enough question, but I wasn't able to find any definite answer anywhere.

If I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2, I need proper licenses for SQL Server; that's fine. It could be per processor, per user... doesn't matter. Let's just assume SQL Server is properly licensed.

If the server is *only* providing database services (it's not a domain controller, nor a web server, it doesn't even share a single folder), do I need Windows Server CALs too?

I would assume not, because that just wouldn't make much sense... but questions like [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/sql-server-2008-r2-on-windows-7-x64-professional-what-are-the-downsides) seem to imply a completely different scenario.

Before someone feels compelled to close this question and send me [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue): I'm not concerned about costs, the actual number of licenses to buy, or the right licensing program to use for my company; I just want a straight answer to the question "do I need Windows Server CALs for a dedicated database server?".

Comment: +1 for a great question. I would agree that if you're not accessing file/print/AD/whatever on that server, then you won't need a CAL

Comment: @Mark, did you actually *read* my question, or did you simply read "licensing" and thought "heck, I need to close this as quickly as possible"?!?

Comment: @massimo, yes I read it. And the last paragraph pretty much sums it up; it's still a question about "do I need x license to do y", which unfortunately is a question topic that has been off topic here for years. From the question you asked not to be linked to: `What CALs do I need to be properly licensed`. If you have a disagreement feel free to open a question on meta.serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

5-second Google: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx#tab=2

In short:

- if SQL Server is licensed per-core, no CALs are required.
- if SQL Server is licensed per-user, you need *both* SQL Server Licenses and CALs.

At least, that's how I read it :)

Comment: That's not what is written there... that pages describes the available licensing models for various Microsoft products, but doesn't say anything at all about the relationships between them.

Comment: Refer to the first tab for those details. That explains that the checkboxes on tab #2 are either/or.

Comment: @adaptr SQL Server CAL != Windows Server CAL. If I understand Massimo correctly, he's asking whether or not you need a Windows Server CAL if you're exclusively using the SQL Services and nothing else.

Comment: I understood that, and while the page is not unambiguously clear, it does talk about *Windows Server* Client CALs.